# Economics Math: Constrained optimization problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, economics

I'm so confused by this problem, that I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question, but here goes...
**Context**
I'm struggling with a constrained optimization problem in economics, where I need to find the maximum utility for given variables.
 In the equation below the utility is expressed as a function of the variable t. The y variable is substituted with the constraint 24-t: 
U(t,y) = U(t, f(24-t))
I'm told to calculate the derivative of the above equation using the chain rule, then differentiate the production function, and then use the composite function rule. The result is here:
$\frac{dU}{dt} = \frac{∂U}{∂t} - \frac{∂U}{∂y}f'(24-t)$
So far I am fine with this. Now I am told that by equating the derivative to zero, I can maximize the utility. Since $\frac{dU}{dt}=0$, the result looks like this:

$\frac{∂U}{∂t} = \frac{∂U}{∂y}f'(24-t)$

I'm confused by the statement 'by equating the derivative to zero, I can maximize the utility."

**Question**
Why does equating the derivative to zero, maximize the utility? I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Is this statement correct (or am I missing the point):
"In order for $\frac{dU}{dt} $ $ to =0$, then $\frac{∂U}{∂t}   must $  $  equal  \frac{∂U}{∂y}f'(24-t)$?" 
In other words, once you equate one side ($\frac{∂U}{∂t}$ ) to the other ($ \frac{∂U}{∂y}f'(24-t)$), you will find the maximum utility?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative measures the slope of the curve at the point for which it is being evaluated. Think of the slope of a line tangent to the curve at that evaluation point. When the slope is zero that means that the tangent line is horizontal to the x-axis. Thus the point is either at a peak in the curve or at the bottom of a valley.

Comment: Thank you. I need to think this through and might come back with a follow-up question, but this seems to be what I'm looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are simply to choose $x$ to maximize a function $U(x)$.

If $U'(x)>0$ then you could increase $x$ and obtain a higher $U$. Conversely, if $U'(x)<0$ then you could reduce $x$ and that you lead to a higher $U$.

Thus, the $x$ that maximizes $U$ must satisfy $U'(x)=0$.